# Github repository initialisation

Tags: git, github, gitlab

In creating a git repository, must the first commit message always be 
in this form

`git commit -m "first commit"`

or you can use any other meaningful message.

Comment: You can use any commit message you want.  But by explicitly stating that this is the first commit, you make it clear to anyone else down the road that this was, in fact, the very first commit to your repository.

Comment: Just a note: one of the great things about computer engineering compared to other engineering fields is that trying things that might fail doesn't cost anything, and doesn't cause any damage. You could have answered your own question by typing another commit message, and see what happens.

Comment: I personally like to add an empty commit at the beginning. Not sure why, but I do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach is to create repository with an initial commit and with `README` file.
Adding `README` file will result in an existing repository which can be cloned

[image]

- You can also initiate a repository with an empty commit:

  ```
  git commit --allow-empty ....
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any meaningful comment.